# How can we Plot 3d image for an average value of 3 dimensional vector by changing 2 elements in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d

I want to plot `z = (x + y + 1)/3` in python3 using 3d capabilituy.
The domain of `x` and `y` are integers and ranging over 30 integer points in [0,29].
I am now facing two problems.

1. The dimension of `x`, `y`, and `z` must be same... 
   Actually, I need 30 points for `x` and `y` while 30*30 = 900 points for `z`.
   In order to plot the thing, I need to increase the number of datapoints of `x` and `y` to 900 as well.
   How can I keep them 30 while successfully plotting?
2. How is the mapping (x, y, z) implemented?
   I'm not sure current my implementation successfully show the result. This is because I do not well understand how `z` is mapped by a pair of `(x,y)`.
   Is my implementation correct?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def my_mean(l):
  k = len(l)
  s = 0.0
  for elem in l:
    s = s + elem
  return s / k


if __name__ == "__main__" :
  N = 30
  x = np.linspace(1, 30, N*N) # I want to make this length 30
  y = np.linspace(1, 30, N*N) # this as well...
  constants = [1] * N*N
  z = []

  for i in range(0, N):
    for j in range(0, N):
      vec = {x[i], y[j], constants[i + N*j]}
      z.append(my_mean(vec)) # is this correct??

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

  ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, label ="Mean")
  ax.set_title("Scatter Plot of Mean")

  ax.set_xlabel('x')
  ax.set_ylabel('y')
  ax.set_zlabel('z')
  ax.legend()

  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at NumPy's [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) function. For two vectors `x` and `y`, it creates 2-D coordinate arrays, which you then can use in vectorized calculations.

To answer your question: Yes, in fact, your actual `x` and `y` (also) need to be `30 x 30` arrays, but as stated above, `meshgrid` will properly generate these for you using your initial vectors of length `30`.

That'd be my (shortened) code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

N = 30
x = np.linspace(1, 30, N)
y = np.linspace(1, 30, N)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = (xx + yy + 1) / 3

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(xx, yy, z, label="Mean")
ax.set_title("Scatter Plot of Mean")
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!